# Open edX full stack version mysql configuration

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, devstack, edx

I am wondering if there is anyone try to use mysql workbench to connect to openedx fullstack version. I have a devstack version which is running on my local machine and doesn't have any issues. Also, I am able to connect to mysql database by using SSH on mysql workbench(devstack).

Please see the official document here: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Developing-on-the-edX-Developer-Stack#the-edx-platform-database-that-devstack-uses

But I am not able to find any document regrading the process of fullstack mysql connection configuration.

Any ideas or suggestions? Appreciate your help!